# How does PubSub work with multiple ESP32s?

Tags: toit

Let's pretend that:

1. I added "cloud:demo/INP" to my account topic with the name INP.
2. I've several ESP32 devices and each of them an application subscribed to receive some message on "cloud:demo/INP":

```
import pubsub
topic ::= "cloud:demo/INP"

main:
  print "wakeup - checking messages"
  pubsub.subscribe topic --blocking=false: | msg/pubsub.Message |
    sender := ?
    if msg.sender.is_device:
      sender = "Device($msg.sender.hardware_id)"
    else:
      sender = "ExternalSystem($msg.sender.external_name)"
    print "Received message '$msg.payload.to_string' from $sender"
```

3. I've an application written in go/java/python/c#/dart/SCALA ... using the toit api, that sends a message to topic "cloud:demo/INP".
   **Will the message be received by all ESP32 devices subscribed to receive messages or only one of them? I guess everyone, although not sure about it.**
4. Now let add one more topic "cloud:demo/OUT" named OUT.
5. Let's change the toit application so that when it receives a message on the "cloud:demo/INP" topic, it sends a message to the "cloud:demo/OUT" topic and deploy this application on several ESP32s:

```
import pubsub

INCOMING_TOPIC ::= "cloud:demo/INP"
OUTGOING_TOPIC ::= "cloud:demo/OUT"

main:
  print "app is started"
  pubsub.subscribe INCOMING_TOPIC --auto_acknowledge: | msg/pubsub.Message |
    print "received: $msg.payload.to_string"
    pubsub.publish OUTGOING_TOPIC msg.payload
    print "sent: $msg.payload.to_string"
```

6. Let's change the go/dart/python ... application that uses the toit api so that it can not only send messages, but also receive them.
   **If I now send some message to topic "cloud:demo/INP", will I receive messages from all ESP32s? If this is true, is there a way to determine which ESP32 device received message belongs to?**

Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toit PubSub does broadcasting - all devices will receive the message.

Every message sent on a topic contains a `publisher` which can either be an `external` or a `device`.

A `device` who publishes will have the `hardware_id` and the `job_id` which is a unique way to determine what device sent the message. to external subscribers we also send `device_id`.

An `external` who publishes will contain the `name` which is the identifier of the external application that published the message. For example in the CLI you can write a message using: `toit pubsub write <topic> <external-name> -- <msg>` here the `<external-name>` will be what is filled into the `publisher.external.name` property.

Comment: 1) How to extract the device id of the message source from the Envelope message received by the external application?
2) If I understood correctly, the only way to send a message to some dedicated ESP32 is to transmit the identifier of this ESP32 in the message. Then the toit application, if it knows the identifier of the ESP32 on which it is running, will be able to filter the messages intended for it. Or is there some other, more intelligent way to solve this problem?